# Execute a shell command programmatically: why it doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, xml, root

I'm trying to programmatically execute the new command "ScreenRecorder" kitkat. I just tried this:

```
suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screenrecord /sdcard/Folder/Example.mp4");
```

But doesn't work. In the Folder I've the file `Example.mp4` but it is empty (0 byte). Why? How can I solve this? Where is the problem? If from terminal emulator I write `su` and press enter and after write `screenrecord /sdcard/Folder/Example.mp4` it works perfectly. Obvisioully I'm running on 4.4.2 and in a rooted terminal.

Comment: This way, su is executed independendly from screenrecord

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: AmanAroraBB Yes, my device is rooted. Read well my question please. 
@deviantfan So I should do something like?

process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("screenrecord /sdcard/Folder/Example.mp4");

Comment: If your version of `su` takes a command as arguments (i.e. it works like `sudo`), then you would use `su screenrecord /sdcard/Folder/Example.mp4`.  Keep an eye on logcat for failure messages.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
public static void ScreenRecord() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.writeBytes("screenrecord --time-limit 10 /sdcard/MyVideo.mp4\n");
            outputStream.flush();

            outputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
            outputStream.flush();
            su.waitFor();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not working for AT#SERVINFO command

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because it's an emulator and not a normal device. I think this article could help in this case: http://russelldavis.blogspot.com/2011/01/rooting-android-emulator.html

Comment: I'm running the application in Runtime on an Android device, not the emulator. With mean terminal emulator i meant the application available in Google Play Store.